# Can I use my letsencrypt wildcard cert on BOTH my webserver and DoH server?

Tags: web-server, ssl-certificate, dns-hosting, unbound

I use letsencrypt wildcard certificate on [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) and it works all fine.

Since it is a wildcard, I can validate SSL on *.mydomain.com.

Now I have a recursive resolver running unbound that I would like to use as a DNS server for my DoH clients ... and that resolver lives at doh.mydomain.com.

See - the resolver has a name that is covered already by the wildcard cert from letsencrypt ... so can I just keep using those keys and certs and NOT regenerate new ones ?

The difficulty I have is that unbound looks for only:

`tls-service-key: "/unbound/domain.key"`

`tls-service-pem: "/unbound/domain.pem"`

... while my webserver uses the output of acme.sh which is:

`cat domain.com.key domain.com.cer >> merged.ssl.pem`

How do I convert my WWW key/cer/pem to what unbound is looking for ?

Many thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [unbound documentation](https://unbound.docs.nlnetlabs.nl/en/latest/topics/privacy/dns-over-https.html#using-doh)...

> Enabling DoH in Unbound is as simple as configuring the TLS
> certificate and the corresponding private key that will be used for
> the connection, and configuring Unbound to listen on the HTTPS port:

so if you have them as in your examples, you would use the pre-cat'd files, something like:

```
server:
    interface: 127.0.0.1@443
    tls-service-key: "/path/to/domain.com.key"
    tls-service-pem: "/path/to/domain.com.cer"
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have done this and from what I can tell, dohclient likes the configuration and I can perform lookups when I query domains from doh.mydomain.com.  However, when I put that address into firefox as my DOH provider, it fails, and in the unbound logs I see:  debug: http2 request invalid, returning :status=404  ...  unfortunately, firefox gives no additional information or useful errors or debugging .. it just says it can't connect.

Comment: You could try  a verbose CLI call like `curl -vv https://...` to try and get additional information